# Default Action Bar displays action menu items only on the main activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have two activities in my app. I want to set two menu items on the default action Bar. They set correctly on the main activity, but in the other activity the action Bar doesn't show them. I still see the Action Bar with the label, but no action menu.

Here is the Manifest file:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity">
    </activity>

</application>
```

Menu Items:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/Settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_white_48dp"
    android:onClick="onClickDoAction"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="Settings">
</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/Share"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_share_white_48dp"
    android:onClick="onClickDoAction"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="Share">
</item>
```

Style:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
</style>
```

And the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

I mention that in the SecondActivity I made nothing in this regard, should I call the onCreateOptionsMenu() there too and so on in every activity?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
```

This line adds the `MenuItem`s to the current `Activity`. You have to do this for every `Activity`.

---

If you have the same menu in each `Activity`, you can call this in a superclass and make all activities extend it. This would help to reduce duplicate code.

Comment: I searched a lot and I found nowhere explicitly that I should call it in every activity, so I thought maybe there is a setting that I don't do right in the Manifest file  that would propagate it to all activities in the app. Seems I was wrong... Thanks a lot!